# How to call DebugActiveProcessStop from disassembled code?

Tags: disassembly, ollydbg, debugging, windbg

I am debugging an application. Another process is debugged by this application.

Here is the call

```
00705435  FF15 C0007500  CALL DWORD PTR DS [<&KERNEL32.ContinueDebugEvent>]
```

I want to change call to `DebugActiveProcessStop`, what should I do ?

Comment: What do you expect to do with those calls ? I mean, you can simply change the EIP to DebugActiveProcessStop whenever you want, or patch the IAT to a code cave that will take the ContinueDebugEvent parameters and use them to call DebugActiveProcessStop, or hook ContinueDebugEvent directly.

Comment: @ASD, what debugger are you using?

Comment: @JasonGeffner am using ollydbg

Comment: @ASD So... Problem solved ?

Comment: @Spl3en yes i solved it.

Comment: @Spl3en please can you provide me your email id i want to talk with you

Comment: @ASD Sure, spl3en.contact at the well known google mail service